# Money exchange in London

Tags: london, exchange

I'm going to London very, very soon and as a traveler beginner, I'm having a huge problem.

I had a problem with my bank (they mess it all and forgot the request I made to exchange money) and now I don't have any pound to take with me before the trip. It means that I'll land in London without a penny in my wallet.

I'll take euros with me and I'm planning use a ATM in the airport so I can have some money to use to get to the center of London but right now I'm looking for a better option to exchange money in London.

Do you know any places where I can exchange some Euros to Pounds without paying ridiculous taxes? I'll be extremely grateful if any of you who knows the best deals, share your knowledge with me!

Comment: Check with your bank what the costs are but for me it is always the cheapest to use the ATM. I do think this question has come along a few times already, so do use the search option here, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-exchange-money-to-gbp-in-london

Comment: You don't *exchange* your Euros - pulling the local currency out of an ATM is always the cheapest option. Note that in many countries the ATM has a question/suggestion about 'converting them' (I forgot the exact wording), to which you always reply 'No' (for the same reason).

Comment: The ATM in the airport usually has higher exchange rates btw; you might also stop at the exchange counter at your departure airport (usually in the international terminal) and change just 50-100 Euro to pounds, just enough to get you started (and, yes, at a ridiculous rate).

Comment: I'm can't remember which bank (maybe Nationwide), but an ATM on the northeast side of Tottenham Court Rd near the Goodge Street station told me upfront that it wouldn't charge a fee for using the ATM with a US card. My bank charged a fee though.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are *extremely* price sensitive, use any ATM you see.  Meaning, don't 'exchange' your Euros.

You will always get the best combined rate (exchange + fee) from any random ATM than you will at any exchange desk.

If a few euros and cents are meaningful to you, you will have to locate an ATM at a bank or on a network that has a favorable relationship with your home bank.  This will save or possibly eliminate the transaction fee.

Also keep in mind that all the trains to London take credit or debit cards.

Comment: So, is there anything wrong with this answer?  Without comment, downvote is totally unwarranted and unhelpful. I'll happily make edits, but I will also defend an otherwise correct answer.